# Where do does a dynamic linker find symbols in Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, linker

I'v been searching all over the web for a resource to learn where exactly linkers find the import. If an import table gives a filename, for example "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll", and a list of symbols needed from that dll, for example `_Unwind_Resume` and `__deregister_frame_info` along with corresponding addresses, what data structure / API / code do I use to actually locate and load the data pointed to by that info?

I've been reading every resource available on the subject and can't seem to pinpoint exactly how this is done. Could any give a minimal example in C, C++ or *any* language, based on the input data available in a Portable Executable import table to retrieve the subroutines referenced? Or even a basic explanation of the API leveraged to find the referenced DLL? I'm looking for any information that can help me further research how this works within Windows.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. The linker generates the import table at build time. The loader processes the import table at run time. This is essentially the equivalent of LoadLibrary() + GetProcAddress() followed by address rebasing if needed.

Comment: @Luke `LoadLibrary` was what I'm looking for, thank you. I'm just learning C++ and don't know many of the API calls, so it's probably obvious but I just didn't know.